# tcpdump -i any doesn't work on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, tcpdump, icmp

How to listen all interfaces on `FreeBSD` with `tcpdump`

```
> tcpdump -i any
tcpdump: any: No such device exists
(BIOCSETIF failed: Device not configured)
```

(I would like to listen ICMP)

Comment: any is a linux specific construct...

Comment: try to run without `-i`.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro what is correct under FreeBSD?

Comment: @YurijGoncharuk `tcpdump any icmp` doesn't work

Comment: As @RuiFRibeiro already stated, "any" is a Linux only option and doesn't work anywhere else. Read the man page.

Comment: man page is here https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?tcpdump(1) it only speaks about `any` on Linux, without describing what to do on FreeBSD

Comment: multiple -i might work, they might me what you need, even though they are not the same thing as any, that is non-promisc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking at this on FreeBSD 11.3 and there doesn't appear to be any way to do an "any".  I thought multiple `-i`s might work, despite the manpage's silence on it, but it only takes the first one.  If tcpdump gets enhanced to support multiple `-i`s then this ought to do it (or you can prove that it doesn't on your system):

```
tcpdump --list-interfaces | grep Running | cut -f 1 -d ' ' | cut -f 2- -d '.' | awk '{ print "-i " $1 }' | xargs -t -Jinterfaces tcpdump interfaces host 8.8.8.8
```

Answer (score 0):

From the tcpdump man page:

> An  interface  argument  of  "all"  or "pktap,all" can be used to capture packets from all interfaces,
>                 including loopback and tunnel interfaces.

Therefore you can simply do, for example:

```
tcpdump -i all tcp port 80
```

If you don't specify the -i flag, then a set of all interfaces are again included in a pseudo interface that by default excludes loopback and tunnel interfaces. Again from the tcpdump man page:

> On  Darwin  systems  version 13 or later, when the interface is unspecified, tcpdump will use a pseudo
>                 interface to capture packets on a set of interfaces determined by  the  kernel  (excludes  by  default
>                 loopback and tunnel interfaces).

Comment: Is this from a Mac OS X machine?  It doesn't seem to be available on FreeBSD 11.3.

Comment: Neither of the quotes you cite appear in [the FreeBSD `man` page for `tcpdump`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=tcpdump&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD+11.4-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html).

Answer (score 0):

I can't vouch for how well this method would serve any particular  use case, but the brute force way to do this in FreeBSD would be to run `N` instances of `tcpdump`, one for each of the `N` interfaces known to `ifconfig`.  You might run them as a grouped and backgrounded command, sending their combined output to a single file.  It seems inevitable that the output file will have numerous duplicated packets, such as showing a packet when it arrives on interface a and then showing it again when it departs on interface b.

But if you really have to do it that way, consider:

```
{
    for i in $(ifconfig -l)
    do
        ( tcpdump -i $i & )
    done
} > tcpdump.out
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to listen all interfaces on FreeBSD with `tcpdump`

[Support capturing on multiple interfaces · Issue #480 · the-tcpdump-group/tcpdump](https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/tcpdump/issues/480) (2015-09-07, open):

- supports [the observation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/604541/13260) by [Bill McGonigle](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/83441/bill-mcgonigle) and others that essentially, it's impossible with [tcpdump(1)](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=tcpdump&sektion=1&manpath=freebsd-release)
- [draws attention](https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/tcpdump/issues/480#issuecomment-138317953) to Wireshark's **dumpcap and (or) TShark**, *which **do** support capturing on multiple interfaces*.

```
% which tshark
/usr/local/bin/tshark
% pkg provides bin/tshark
Name    : wireshark-nox11-4.0.7
Comment : Powerful network analyzer/capture tool (without GUI)
Repo    : FreeBSD
Filename: usr/local/bin/tshark

Name    : wireshark-4.0.7
Comment : Powerful network analyzer/capture tool
Repo    : FreeBSD
Filename: usr/local/bin/tshark
% pkg search -oq wireshark
net/wireshark
net/wireshark
% man -P less tshark
% man -P less dumpcap
%
```

**net/wireshark** in FreshPorts:

- https://www.freshports.org/net/wireshark/

**dumpcap(1)** in FreeBSD ports:

- https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=dumpcap&sektion=1&manpath=freebsd-ports

**tshark(1)** in FreeBSD ports:

- https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=tshark&sektion=1&manpath=freebsd-ports
- mentions *ICMP*.

Answer (score -3):

As with anything in FreeBSD:
Reading the manpage usually explains everything.

```
       -i interface
   --interface=interface
      Listen on interface.  If unspecified, tcpdump searches the  sys-
      tem interface list for the lowest numbered, configured up inter-
      face (excluding loopback), which may turn out to be,  for  exam-
      ple, ``eth0''.

      On  Linux  systems with 2.2 or later kernels, an interface argu-
      ment of ``any'' can be used to capture packets from  all  inter-
      faces.   Note  that  captures  on the ``any'' device will not be
      done in promiscuous mode.

      If the -D flag is supported, an interface number as  printed  by
      that flag can be used as the interface argument, if no interface
      on the system has that number as a name.
```

https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=tcpdump&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+12.1-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html

Comment: "On Linux systems"?